# Where can I find information about customizing custom post types?

Tags: wordpress, metadata, custom-post-type

Despite my searching I can't seem to get good information.  I just need to know where to start.

I have set up a custom post type correctly. However, I would like to customize the information it asks for then save that information.  I have found guides and info in the codex that says how to save the information from the fields, but I can't seem to locate how to remove the default title and editor and add my own fields.

I found a plugin that will do it, but I would like to learn how to do it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can answer your question:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44966/how-can-i-add-extra-attribute-in-the-page-attribute-section-in-wp-admin-for-pa

As Christopher says:

> All the content on the post editting screen, with the exception of the
>   main editor and title area, is a meta box. You can remove them by
>   calling [remove_meta_box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box), then replace them with your own.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a little on how much you want to customize them.

To remove the default title and editor, take a look at the `supports` argument in [the register_post_type codex entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments).  Passing an empty array should remove them.

For adding fields, you can use the [add_meta_box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) function, much as you would for posts.

Comment: That looks like the ticket.  Thanks!